# differential equation with shifted argument

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am trying to solve, in general, the following differential equation :

$ y(x+a) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}y(x) $

With $y :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and  $~a\in \mathbb{R}$

Do you know of any techniques to solve such a differential equation ?

Any input appreciated

Comment: I don't know the techniques, but I know the phrase to search for: differential-delay equation.

Comment: The usual starting point: $y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$.

Comment: the restriction of $y$ to any interval of length $a$ determines $y$ completely, and there isn't many constraints on what $y$ can do on such an interval, so locally there isn't much you can say. The behaviour of solutions as $x \to \pm \infty$ may be of more interest but I'm really not sure how to tackle that.

Comment: Use power series solution assuming $y(x)=$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} b_r.x^r$.

Comment: The Ansatz of Jonas seems to work but the problem is that in the end an equation of the type $e^{\lambda a}\lambda^2=1$ needs to be solved for $\lambda$. Seems like the problem is doomed :). Thanks for the help.

Comment: $$e^{\lambda a} = \lambda^2 \iff -\frac{\lambda a}{2} e^{-\frac{\lambda a}{2}} = -\frac{a}{2} \implies -\frac{\lambda a}{2} = W\left(-\frac{a}{2}\right) \implies \lambda = -\frac{2}{a}W\left(-\frac{a}{2}\right)$$
where $W(\cdot)$ is any branch of [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: Well, indeed you will always have the problem that you mention (it is also usual) but it is the best approach (do have a look at Hale's first edition of "Introduction to Functional Differential Equations", better than the second edition).